How also notify post creator when creating a post to a channel via MS Teams Workflows
I configured my project to use template "Post to a Teams chat using an incoming webhook" from Microsoft Teams Workflows. I was provided with a webhook that will create new messages on my Teams chat.

But I'm having a small issue. The new message is created with my user as the author. Because I'm the author, I don't receive a notification in my activity list.
What can I do to enable the notification to the author of the new message (me in this case).

If your card is meant to be posted in team's channel, they you won't get any option. However, if it is configured to be posted in 'Chat with Flow bot' then you can set IsAlert property to Yes and you will get activity feed notification. https://i.sstatic.net/E4LMiisZ.png

Thanks @Prasad-MSFT. Could you transfer your comment to a answer?

I have transferred. Thanks!

If your card is meant to be posted in team's channel, then you won't get any option.
However, if it is configured to be posted in 'Chat with Flow bot' then you can set IsAlert property to Yes and you will get activity feed notification.

